# Cloudshare with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cloud, share

I am trying to get a simple search going but for lack of examples seem to be stuck... Can anyone tell me what might be wrong here? I am getting the following error and I am not sure why...

*"/Guzzle/Service/Client.php:207: Fatal Error: Method call 'setState' is not allowed for a null value. "*

My source:

```
<?php
     require 'aws-autoloader.php';
     use Aws\Common\Aws;
     use Aws\Common\Region;
     use Aws\CloudSearch\CloudSearchClient;
     use Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient;
     use Aws\Common\Client\ClientBuilder;
     use Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model;

    $config = array(
        'key'    => '<key>',
        'secret' => '<secret>',
        'base_url' => 'search-<searchdomain>.us-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com',
        'region' => 'us-west-1'
      );

    $client = CloudSearchClient::factory($config);

    $domainClient = $client->getDomainClient('<searchdomain>', array(
        'credentials' => $client->getCredentials(),
    ));

    $result = $domainClient ->search(array('query' => 'foo'));
    $hitCount = $result->getPath('hits/found');
    echo "Number of Hits: {$hitCount}\n";
?>
```

I would appreciate any help... thank you.

Comment: done any basic debugging to figure out WHICH of your method calls are triggering this error?

Comment: Thanks Marc, not sure how to go about debugging this... I have commented out most of the statements and it seems to be in the line:    $domainClient = $client->getDomainClient('<searchdomain>', array(
        'credentials' => $client->getCredentials(),
    ));  Not sure why...

Comment: what's with the comma here: `->getCredentials(), ))`? that'd be treated as an empty/missing parameter, and if that method is defined with `$missingarg = null`...

Comment: According the Cloudshare howto on AWS that line is supposed to get credentials from the client. It could be it just doesn't work.  I'll have to check to see about providing the credentials instead and get back...

Comment: Added:  use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials;

$credentials = new Credentials(‘<key>’, ‘<secret>’); 

Changed:

$domainClient = $client->getDomainClient(‘<searchdomain>’, array('credentials' => $credentials));

Still same error…

Comment: Of course we are talking about Cloudsearch not Cloudshare...